# Not getting the binary search algorithm correct

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, binary-search

I am trying to implement `binary search` and I did the following:

```
function bs(a,x) {
    // a : array to look into
    // x : number to find
    let mpoint = Math.floor(a.length / 2);
    if(x >= a[mpoint]) {
        if(x == a[mpoint]) { return mpoint;}
        else {
            return bs([...a].slice(mpoint,a.length), x)
        }
    }else {
        if(x == a[mpoint]) {return mpoint;}
        else {
            return bs([...a].slice(0,mpoint),x)
        }
    }
}


bs([ 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 ], 10)
```

But I get an incorrect `index` as a result. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: The if inside the else makes no sense since there is no way x can be equal in that section.

Comment: The index is correct but apparently it is of the sliced array. So add the `mpoint`.

Comment: The `[...a]` spread literal is superfluous, `slice` creates a new array anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change:

```
return bs([...a].slice(mpoint,a.length), x)
```

to:

```
return bs([...a].slice(mpoint,a.length), x) + mpoint
```